# Unreserved characters in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, parsing

I need to encode all occurrence of `<` character in a C/C++ code file. To prevent conflict, I need to know which characters are not reserved in C/C++ standard. For example, if `$` is not reserved, I can encode `<` to `$` temporarily and revive the original C/C++ code later.

I need this encoding for my C/C++ code in the XML-like intermediate language.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you convert all `<` characters to `$`, how will you preserve any instances of `$` in your original file?

Since you say you're targeting an XML-like intermediate language, why not use XML escaping and convert `<` to `&lt` instead?  (You'll also need to convert `&` in that case, say to `&amp`.)  There are lots of open source libraries available to help you do this.  If you can't find any stand-alone module, [here's code I've written](https://github.com/openhome/ohNet/blob/master/OpenHome/Converter.cpp) which could have its XML (un)escaping functionality extracted.

Comment: Thanks. You did exactly what I want! Unfortunately, I am in python and yours in C++. According to your code, are `>`, `<`, `&`, `'`, and `"` the only conflicting characters between C/C++ and XML?

Comment: @ahmad There aren't any conflicting characters between C/C++ and XML as such, there are just characters that are represented by a series of characters in XML.  Your list of these characters is correct.  I'm sure there will be standard functions in Python to (un)escape XML but you could easily write your own code too using this list of characters.

Comment: @ahmad See http://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingXml for some notes on python support for XML

Comment: Your post is not the answer of my question, but this is the solution of my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Rather than list unreserved characters (there are infinite), here are the reserved ones from 2.3.1 of the standard:

```
space, horizontal tab, vertical tab, form feed, new line
a through z
A through Z
0 through 9
_ { } [ ] # ( )  % : ; . ? * + - / ^ & | ~ ! = , \ " '
```

[image]

Comment: Fair enough, but does this really help the OP, especially given that any non-trivial program would contain string literals?

Comment: @NPE Probably not as helpful as he would want as this is an XY problem.  simonc's answer seems more helpful.

Comment: The @simonc has solved my main problem. However, this is the answer to my question.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it is wrong.  It lists the
minimum set of characters an implementation is _required_ to
support directly (and even then, it's possible to use trigraphs
to avoid some of them).  Further characters can be specified by
universal character names, and implementations can accept them
directly.  (All of the implementations I know accept `"@$"`, for
example, and at least one accepts things like `àéç` as a symbol.)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "reserved".  An implementation
is only required to understand a very limited number of
characters in input, with all others being input by means of
universal character names.  An implementation is allowed (and
I would even say encouraged) to support more, see §2.2, point 1.
In practice, there are (or should be) *no* reserved characters
in comments, and in string and character literals (at least the
wide character forms, and in C++11, the Unicode forms).  Your
best bet is probably something like quoted printable.